# Why can't I scale this image in my header?

Tags: html, css, header, background-image

I'm new to HTML/CSS and I'm trying out what I've learned so far.

I have a header set up but I want a background image within the header. No matter what I do, I can't get the image to be at scale in the header. It either tiles or is so big that I can't see the image in the header.

Here is my working code so far:

```
<style>
header {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
        color: #AA1166;
        max-height: 500px;
        background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/8ClzWQ5.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
```

Again, I'm new so maybe I'm trying to accomplish something that I haven't learned the proper code for. Can someone shed some light?

Comment: you're doing it right, you should clarify your question, what exactly are you expecting? also try changing `background-position` to `top` for example and see if it helps. you also better use a rectangular image that has the same ratio of your header element

Comment: I downloaded a photo that is 400x310 and I would like to see the entire photo fit within the header, however, it's only showing parts of it or being tiled. This is day 3 of learning so I'm not sure if my thought process of being able to scale the photo within the header is the first problem...

Comment: Is it `contain` that you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/L2z31j9q/

Answer (score 0):

*I want a background image within the header*

Please check codes below.

```
<style type="text/css">
header {
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
color: #AA1166;
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/b6y6Xvb.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-color: #666;
width:960px;
height: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
header {
   background: url(http://i.imgur.com/8ClzWQ5.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
   color: #AA1166;
   min-height:300px;
   max-height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the code below

```
header {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
        color: #AA1166;
        height: 500px;
        background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/8ClzWQ5.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center top;
        background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

you are missing the `height` property